# Node.js: password trouble

Tags: javascript, mysql, string, node.js, node-webkit

i have a strange problem with my nodejs module mysql

i'm trying to connect node with mysql

on the connection i have something like this

```
client.password = 'password';
```

an it connects correctly but if i get the password from a variable like this

```
var pass = "password"
client.password = pass;
```

the annoying msg "Access denied..." apears

I have this trouble only on windows, in linux the code works fine...

Any help... please?

so, i'm using node-webkit in my project

---

Update

I have this extactly code, previuosly i set the localStorage and the sessionStorage variables by obtaining the values from a form

```
   Client = require('mysql').Client;
   client = new Client();

    client.host = localStorage.ip;  
    client.port = parseInt(localStorage.puerto);    
    client.user = localStorage.user;
    client.password = sessionStorage.pass;
    client.multipleStatements = true;

    client.on("error", function(err) {
        econexion = true;
        throw err;
    });
```

And it works perfectly over linux x86 and linux x64 but in windows simply doesn't work, bit if i put the password like a direct String it works "fine", some like this

```
Client = require('mysql').Client;
   client = new Client();

    client.host = localStorage.ip;  
    client.port = parseInt(localStorage.puerto);    
    client.user = localStorage.user;
    client.password = "secret";
    client.multipleStatements = true;

    client.on("error", function(err) {
        econexion = true;
        throw err;
    });
```

i changed the sessionStorage by localStorage, but it's the same, and the other props works without problems

thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Skype was the blame in this problem, the skype services causes a conflict, i change the skype configuration and restart my computer, it's works fine, thanks for the answers and i hope this solution helps somebody else

Answer (score -2):

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'example.org',
  user     : 'bob',
  password : 'secret',
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  // connected! (unless `err` is set)
});
```